# open source code where command and vistor patterns are implemented

Tags: design-patterns

Is there any open source code where I can see some design patterns like command, state pattern being implemented for practical use.

I have theoretically seen the implementation of various patterns but it would rather help if I can see its practical use.

Currently I am working in a project which has workflow and the various steps in workflow is fetched from the database.

Can this be one place where command pattern be used by making each step in workflow be made as a command and then use the command pattern?

Comment: Just google "design pattern visitor some language" Loads of examples on the t'internet.

Comment: I can implement the pattern but what i wanted to know is some practical usage of it in some open source code.

Comment: You will be better off looking for patterns in your design, and then choosing the pukka implementation of them. You seem to be working on the architecural cookie cutter approach, won't teach you anything worth knowing. Study the patterns, look at your needs which pattern satisfy it, or not.

Answer (score 2):

That might be hard to take, but strict application of design patterns finds little to no practical usage. Proper solution almost never consists *solely* of applied pattern; a lot depends on the programming language, actual problem, and developer preference.

For example, typical Java-OOP approach to extracting data from DB could look like you've described, however someone using a language with functional possibilities might well use `Optional` Monad for it, producing not necessarily worse, but completely different solution for the same problem.

Thus, in your solutions you should solve problems with general principles of good design, like DRY, and idioms of your programming language in mind, instead of looking at everything as a nail (the hammer being the pattern you *want to use*).

*Strangely* enough, excessive use of patterns is typical to Java language, and you don't have to look far for a lot of stuff like Factories of Managers of Singletons of ...